# Does anyone know a specific polynomial-time algorithm to detect if a given signed graph contains an odd-K4 as a signed minor?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-minors

By signed graph, I mean each edge is designated either odd or even (e.g. as in Guenin's result for weakly bipartite graphs).

Comment: Isn't brute force a polynomial time algorithm?  Gerhard "Six Is Smaller Than N?" Paseman, 2017.04.19.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman There isn't a polynomial brute force algorithm if you want to test for minors.  Brute force only works if you want to test if you have an odd-K_4 as a subgraph.

Comment: Really? I guess I do not understand. I thought iterating over 4-tuples of vertices and doing a polynomial amount of work at each tuple is what is required. Maybe a minor is more like a quotient? Gerhard "Easily Gets These Things Confused" Paseman, 2017.04.19.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor is fairly informative - edge contractions are the piece you're missing.

Comment: (And note that testing a given 4-tuple of vertices by just looking for paths between all pairs of the 4-tuple doesn't work, because those paths aren't guaranteed to be disjoint from each other.)

Comment: OK. Thanks. Gerhard "Continues The Battle Against Ignorance" Paseman, 2017.04.19.

Comment: Gerhard, also note that in the above comment Steven tacitly uses the fact that a signed graph $G$ contains an odd $K^4$ as a minor if and only if $G$ contains an odd $K^4$ as a topological minor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in my [PhD thesis](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/handle/10012/4716), we prove the stronger result that for any fixed signed graph $(G, \Sigma)$, there is a polynomial-time algorithm to test if an input signed graph contains a $(G, \Sigma)$-minor.  Actually, we prove the stronger result that for any abelian group $\Gamma$, testing for a fixed $\Gamma$-labelled minor can be done in polynomial time (signed graphs correspond to the case $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$).

As a word of warning, the algorithm is rather complicated.  For example, the special case that $\Gamma$ is the trivial group includes minor testing (for graphs), which requires much of the Graph Minors machinery developed by Robertson and Seymour.

If you only care about odd-$K_4$-minors, there is an easier algorithm of Kawarabayashi, Li and Reed [here](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9781611973075.27).

Answer (score 3):

As a consequence of

[Seymour, P.D., The matroids with the max-flow min-cut property, JCT B, 23 (1977), p. 189-222],

a finite signed graph has an odd $K^4$ as signed minor

if and only if

the system $\mathcal{S}$ of linear inequalities defining
its negative-circuit-incidence-vector-polyhedron 
is *totally dual integral*.

As a consequence of [Cook, W., Lovász, L., Schrijver, A., A polynomial-time test for total dual integrality in fixed dimension (1984)] there exists an algorithm which decides in time polynomial in the number of edges of the given graph, whether $\mathcal{S}$ is totally dual integral.

I am not sure whether this conforms with your request for a *specific* algorithm, *specific* being an informal notion. Right off the bat I am unsure how much the result of Cook--Lovász--Schrijver has been improved in the intervening thirty years. 
Should you decide to further pursue this direction (i.e., not working with the combinatorics proper but passing to a system of linear inequations, then 
it might help to

keep in mind that the above-mentioned system of linear inequalities is a 
zero-one-system

have a look at recent work of 
Chudnovsky, Cornuéjols, Liu, Seymour and Vušković.